How to automate a non-standard app with applescript?
I'm trying to automate an application that's very non-standard using System Events, which seems to be recommended.
However, the only thing System Events can find is something called "menu bar 1". For example:
activate application "Foo"
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Foo"
        click at {500, 500}
    end tell
end tell

prints
menu bar 1 of application process "Foo" of application "System Events"

I can ask what UI Elements are in the app:
activate application "Foo"
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Foo"
        UI Elements
    end tell
end tell

which prints
get every UI element of process "Foo"
        --> {menu bar 1 of application process "Foo"}

The menu bar itself has no real actions available. How can I get access to the main content of the app so I can click on things?

UI elements are in hierarchical order. So try to "get every UI element of menu bar 1 of application process "Foo", and it will give you the list of items (menus). Then one level down with the 2nd menu of the menu bar 1: "get every UI element item 2 of menu bar 1 of application process "Foo". and so on...

You can also get entire contents of…, which will get the entire tree structure. Of course, this could generate a long list so I generally use @pbell's approach until I run into a wall. Then I'll go up one level and use 'entire contents of…' to get a partial tree.

@pbell @Mockman But it's just the menu bar, no actual content. So even get entire contents of just lists all of the menu bar items, and doesn't say anything about the content of the app itself. But there is an app! I can see it! It has rendered lists and buttons and everything! It seems like Appscript's UI hierarchy doesn't know the app even exists apart from the menu, hence my question: how can I get access to the main content of the app?

If no menu bar, I still expect the application has some UI elements. So "get every UI elements of application process "Foo" should give you some objects. I guess if no menu bar, at least a window...? then you will have to use again same hierarchy as explained in previous answers (Mockman and me)

Alas, it doesn't. Any other thoughts?
